# set class if index exist in array using filters

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In AnugularJs I want to add a css class if the row index exist an an int array ( $scope.AssociateCandidatesIndex ) using filters, any idea how do i achieve this?

```
     <tr ng-show="true" class="{{ $index}}">

</tr>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not using filters, but something like this should work:

```
<tr ng-show="true" 
    ng-class="{ 'yourCssClass' : AssociateCandidatesIndex.indexOf($index) > -1 }">
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 data-ng-class="$index? 'yourClass' : '' "
```

try this it should add `yourClass` if `$index` exists

Comment: This wont work, what if index is 0? that is a valid index but will resolve to false

Comment: @NilesTanner  index = 0 would mean that it is the first element  , but if you want to exclude the first element then  just use  $index > 0  instead of $index